# PHP HTML Images in a directory table

Tags: php, html, mysql, image

Any idea how i can generate a table with the images I have in a directory, example, Assignment directory? I have tried a number of options but I cant get this sorted.

Ideally I have the name of the corresponding item (obtained from a mysql db via php) in the table.

Tried this which is very basic but it does not work:

```
<?php
     $files = scandir('/var/www/html/Assignment');
     foreach($files as $file) {
     if($file !== "." && $file !== "..") {
        echo "<img height="30" width="30" src='$file'/>"
    }
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: Define _does not work_

Comment: This should fix your code (the height and width values should have single quotation marks and you need to add the path to your image src in this case I'm guessing it is Assignment/): <?php
     $files = scandir('/var/www/html/Assignment');
     foreach($files as $file) {
        if($file !== "." && $file !== "..") {
          echo "<img height='30' width='30' src='Assignment/".$file."' />";
        }
      }
 ?>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code..

```
    $files = ""; //path to directory
    $Image = glob("" . $files. "{*.jpg,*.gif,*.png}", GLOB_BRACE);        

    foreach($Image as $newImage)
    {
       echo '<img height="30" width="30" src="'.$newImage.'"/>'.'</br>';        
    }
```

Comment: This works however I still get blank images:Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: yeah thats what i did: <?php
    $files = "/var/www/html/Assignment";

Comment: <img src='Assignment/'

Comment: yes @Grant ... shaun your image src field may be wrong

Comment: yes i tried Assignment/ and /Assignment/* and still not luck :/

Comment: /var/www/html/Assignment returns an output in cli, but on browser I get 404s

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function dirlist($dir, $bool = "dirs"){
  $truedir = $dir;
  $dir = scandir($dir);
  if($bool == "files"){ 
     $direct = 'is_dir';
  } elseif($bool == "dirs"){
     $direct = 'is_file';
  }
  foreach($dir as $k => $v){
     if(($direct($truedir.$dir[$k])) || $dir[$k] == '.' || $dir[$k] == '..' ){
        unset($dir[$k]);
     }
  }
  $dir = array_values($dir);
  return $dir;
}

$allimages = dirlist("/path/to/images");
foreach($allimages as $key => $value){
   echo "<img src='images/".$value."'alt=''>\n";
}
```